# Is there any CakePHP function that builds and executes the query without returning the result set

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, fetch, cakephp-2.1

I'm using CakePHP 2.1.3. I have a performance problem of looping a large set of array data returned from [`find('all')`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.1.3/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L2689). I want to retrieve a query result row by row to eliminate this expensive array processing. I don't want the result set of array returning from [`find()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.1.3/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L2689) or [`query()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.1.3/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L2689). What I'm trying to do is like below:

```
$db = $this->Model->getDataSource();

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM my_table';
if($result = $db->execute($sql){
  $db->resultSet($result);
  while($row = $db->fetchResult()){
     // do something with $row
  }
}
```

However, I don't want to write the raw query. Is there any Cake function that just builds the query according to the association set and executes it without returning the result set?

#### [Edit]

I'm currently implementing the above script in controller. My model has no associations and so I don't need to use `recursive = -1`. It is the whole table fetching for the purpose of CSV export.

The Cake's `find()` has an internal array processing and the returned result set has to be looped again explicitly. I want to optimize the code by avoiding the array processing of large data twice.

Related issue: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/6426

Answer (score 0):

At first be sure, that you only fetch the data you really yreally need. Ideally you get everything you need with $this->YourModel->recursive = -1
Often performance problems arise due to many connected data.

When you have checked this I think a loop would be the best solution where you fetch the desired data in chunks via an between condition. Although I am not sure if this will help you.

Why do you want to go through the whole table? Do you perform some maintenance like e.g. filling a new field or updating a counter? Maybe you can achieve the goal better than by trying to fetch a whole table.

Comment: I guess fetching it by chunks would be the best solution. Iterrate through ids or dates or what is good for your request. But if we talk about such big amount of data I guess you will want to write the exported data also chunkwise to a file and not hold all the extracted data in the ram and deliver it in one action.